# VBS Ошибка при сохранении файла Word

Tags: ms-word, office, vbscript, wsh

Скрипт VBS. Пытаюсь сохранить файл Word из формата doc в формат docx.
Если не указываю расширение сохраняемого файла, WSH выдает ошибку "Неверно указано имя файла" 800A1420. Если указать расширение docx, то "Тип и расширение файла не совместимы" 800A18696. Задавал второй параметр: тип файла, пробовал `SaveAs2`. Ситуация не изменилась. Понимаю, что что-то делаю не так, но что не понятно.

```
Option Explicit
Const msoFileDialogOpen  = 1
Const wdDoNotSaveChanges = 0
Dim strText
Dim strPath
Dim strFileName
Dim strFileNameMask
strPath     = "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Мои документы\"
strFileNameMask = "*.doc"
strFileName = "A1.docx"
With WScript.CreateObject("Word.Application")
    .Visible = True
    With .FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName  = strPath & strFileNameMask
        If .Show() = -1 Then
            With .Application.Documents.Open(.SelectedItems.Item(1))
                strText = .Range.Text
                    .SaveAs strPath & strFileName
            End With
        End If
    End With
    .Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges
End With
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Стоит задача автоматической обработки файлов или нужно каждый раз вручную выбирать необходимый документ **.doc** и пересохранять его в .docx?

Comment: Задача стоит открытый файл .doc пересохранить в .docx

Comment: Не понял комментария.Еще раз спрошу: нужно это делать автоматически или пользователь должен вручную подтверждать каждую операцию: выбор файла для открытия, выбор пути и имени для пересохранения и т.д. ?

Comment: Не вижу особой разницы. Пусть вручную, что от этого изменится? Скрипт перед глазами, все вроде понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вызвать процедуру **пере**сохранения **SaveAs**.
Этой процедуре нужно указать формат сохраняемого файла. Для [docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464698/) этот параметр равен **12**

Соответственно нужно в скрипте изменить строку сохранения на следующую:

```
            .SaveAs strPath & strFileName , 12
```

Comment: Из своего опыта скажу, что у меня возникала задача массовой обработки нескольких каталогов с сотнями вложенных файлов **doc/docm**. При этом содержимое каталогов менялось, требуя автоматизировать процесс пересохранения файлов в формат **docx**. Лучшим для меня решением стало объединить все процедуры: поиск файлов, пересохранение и лог в единый макрос-файл. Который и вызывался по расписанию, получая значение пути обрабатываемого каталога как параметр.

Comment: Извините меня, но вы внимательно прочитали мой вопрос? По-моему я про это уже писал, а именно "Задавал второй параметр: тип файла, пробовал SaveAs2. Ситуация не изменилась." Просто добавлю, что с SaveAs то же самое.

Comment: Я лично проверил скрипт с измененным кодом, на офисе 2016 все отработало

Comment: Я лично проверил скрипт, на офисе 2010 не работает выдает "Неверно указано имя файла".

Comment: Опять таки, проверил скрипт на MS Office 2010 - все работает. Остается задать простые вопросы. А у вас путь, указанный в переменной **strPath** существует? И правильно ли указана кодировка VBS-файла - WIN1251 ?

Comment: Думаю вам нечего мне подсказать, поэтому спасибо и до свидания.